# Best practice: Initialization of different static private parameters when inerits in different classes

Tags: c++11, inheritance, static

I have two classes `Class A` and `Class B` objects, that inherits from `Class C`. `Class C` containts static private parameters that I would like to initialize with different values in `Class A` and `Class B`. `Class A` and `Class B` are in fact containers filled with some mathematical operations. And `Class B`  takes a `Class A` element as argument in the constructor.

As I initialize the static private parameters of `Class C` at the begining of `Class A` and `Class B`, I get a `multiple definition of C::m_paramC` error.

Please find below a scheme of the setup and some information about how the classes are implemented:
[image]

**A.H**

```
class A: public C
{
public:
    Type methodsA()
private:
    Type m_paramA;
}
```

**A.CPP**

```
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

Type C::m_paramC = something;

Type A::methodsA()
{
}
```

It is similar for `Class B` without the include to B and the static parameter from C should be with different value compared to A `Type C::m_paramC = something_else;`.

**C.H**

```
class C
{
public:
Template<class T>
Type C::methodsC()
{
   /* use of m_paramC */
}
private:
    static Type m_paramC;
}
```

The `template<T>` in C.H allows to perform the same operations on objects from A or B.
So, my question is the following: what is the best practice to link together classes on the way described above and be able to change in A and B the values of the private parameters of C?

In fact, I am trying to use m_paramC in my static functions and in the same time I need m_paramC to change depending on if it comes from objects of type A or objects of type B

---

**EDIT: Please find attached below a minimal example as suggested by Ted Lyngmo**

**example.pro**

```
QT -= gui
QT += sql

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        a.cpp \
        b.cpp \
        c.cpp \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    a.h \
    b.h \
    c.h
```

**a.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "QString"
#include "c.h"

class A: public C
{
public:
    A(const QString &, const double &);
    A();

    void setParamA(const double &);
    const double& getParamA() const;

    void setMemberId(const QString &);
    const QString& getMemberId() const;


private:
    QString m_memberId;
    double m_paramA;

    //**************************************************************//
    //***********************SERIALIZATION**************************//
    //**************************************************************//

    friend QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const A &a)
    {
        out << a.getMemberId() << a.getParamA();
        return out;
    }

    friend QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, A &a)
    {
        QString memberId;
        double paramA;

        in >> memberId >> paramA;

        a.setMemberId(memberId);
        a.setParamA(paramA);

        return in;
    }


};

#endif // A_H
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"

QString C::m_connectionName = "aDB";
QString C::m_pathDatabase = "dbA.db";


A::A(const QString &memberId, const double & param):
    m_memberId(memberId),
    m_paramA(param)
{

}

A::A()
{

}

void A::setParamA(const double &x)
{
    m_paramA = x;
}

const double & A::getParamA() const
{
    return m_paramA;
}

void A::setMemberId(const QString &x)
{
    m_memberId = x;
}

const QString & A::getMemberId() const
{
    return m_memberId;
}
```

**b.h**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H


#include "QString"
#include "a.h"
#include "c.h"

class B: public C
{
public:
    B(const QString &, const A &);
    B();

    void setParamB(const double &);
    const double& getParamB() const;

    void setMemberId(const QString &);
    const QString& getMemberId() const;


private:
    QString m_memberId;
    double m_paramB;


    //**************************************************************//
    //***********************SERIALIZATION**************************//
    //**************************************************************//

    friend QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const B &b)
    {
        out << b.getMemberId() << b.getParamB();
        return out;
    }

    friend QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, B &b)
    {
        QString memberId;
        double paramB;

        in >> memberId >> paramB;

        b.setMemberId(memberId);
        b.setParamB(paramB);

        return in;
    }

};


#endif // B_H
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include "b.h"


/*
QString C::m_connectionName = "bDB";
QString C::m_pathDatabase = "dbB.db";
*/

//I want here to be able to connect to a different database but if I remove the comments, I have the famous error


B::B(const QString &memberId, const A & a):
    m_memberId(memberId),
    m_paramB(a.getParamA() / 2)
{

}

B::B()
{

}

void B::setParamB(const double &x)
{
    m_paramB = x;
}

const double & B::getParamB() const
{
    return m_paramB;
}

void B::setMemberId(const QString &x)
{
    m_memberId = x;
}

const QString & B::getMemberId() const
{
    return m_memberId;
}
```

**c.h**

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#include "QString"
#include "QDebug"
#include "QtSql"

class C
{
public:
    C();
    static void initConnectionToDB();
    static void createNewTableInDB( const QString &);
    static QSqlDatabase connectToDB();
    static void closeConnectionToDB();

    template <class T>
    static QByteArray object2blob( const T& u )
    {
      QByteArray blob;
      QDataStream bWrite( &blob, QIODevice::WriteOnly );
      bWrite << u;
      return blob;
    }

    template <class T>
    static T blob2object( const QByteArray& blob, T& t)
    {
      QDataStream bRead( blob );
      bRead >> t;
      return t;
    }

    template <class T>
    static void saveToDB(const T& t, const QString & tableID, const QString & memberId)
    {
        QSqlQuery query(connectToDB());

        query.prepare( "INSERT INTO " + tableID + " (memberId,objectBlob) VALUES (:memberId,:objectBlob)" );
        query.bindValue(":memberId", memberId);
        query.bindValue(":objectBlob",  object2blob<T>(t) );
        if( !query.exec() )
        {
            qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    static T readFromDB(const QString & tableID, const QString & memberId )
    {
        QSqlQuery query(connectToDB());
        query.prepare( "SELECT * FROM " + tableID + " WHERE memberId ='"+ memberId +"'" );
        T t;
        if ( !query.exec() )
        {
            qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        }
        else
        {
            if ( !query.next())
            {
                qDebug()<<"Not in the database";
            }
            else
            {
                t = blob2object<T>( query.value( 1 ).toByteArray(), t );
            }
        }
        return t;
    }

protected:
    static QString m_connectionName;
    static QString m_pathDatabase;

};

#endif // C_H
```

**c.cpp**

```
#include "c.h"

C::C()
{

}

void C::initConnectionToDB()
{
    QSqlDatabase myDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", QStringLiteral("%1").arg(m_connectionName));
    myDB.setDatabaseName(m_pathDatabase);
    if (!myDB.open())
    {
        qDebug()<<myDB.lastError().text();
    }
}

QSqlDatabase C::connectToDB()
{
    return QSqlDatabase::database(QStringLiteral("%1").arg(m_connectionName));
}

void C::closeConnectionToDB()
{
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(QStringLiteral("%1").arg(m_connectionName));
}

void C::createNewTableInDB( const QString &tableId)
{
    QSqlQuery query(C::connectToDB());
    query.prepare( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableId + " (memberId TEXT, objectBlob BLOB)" );
    if( !query.exec() )
    {
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    A::initConnectionToDB();
    B::initConnectionToDB();


    A::createNewTableInDB("testTableA");


    A a1("pA", 6);
    a1.saveToDB(a1,"testTableA", "memberA1");

    A a2 = A::readFromDB<A>("testTableA", "memberA1");
    qDebug()<<a2.getMemberId()<<a2.getParamA();



    B::createNewTableInDB("testTableB");


    B b1("memberB1",a1);
    b1.saveToDB(b1, "testTableB", "memberB1");


    A::closeConnectionToDB();
    B::closeConnectionToDB();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Exactly, that is why I have a problem. I would like these parameters change for objects of A or objects of B. I try this way but as you mentionned, I cant have this. Is there another way to be able to change m_paramC for objects A and objects B knowing that I have static methods? I will try to provide a minimal example as fast as possible. m_privateParam  is in fact m_paramC. I edit my question.

Comment: In fact, I am trying to use m_paramC in my static functions and in the same time I need m_paramC to change depending on if it comes from objects of type A or objects of type B

Comment: I see... How could I proceed then? How can I make available a private parameter in my static methods without using a static private parameter ?

Comment: My C class is a qtsql manager. It writes the objects A and B as a BLOB in a database. However, the database path and the connection name are different for A and B (that s my member variables in C). The problem is that, the static methods of C cant access the normal member variable of C if they are not static as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208879/discussion-between-froz-and-ted-lyngmo).